# Corrupted DB Server - Preparing to restore

Tags: 2010, backup

Several of our database servers have been corrupted - this occurred after a patch, but we are still unsure of the root cause. We are moving through the servers and restoring them to a clean state. We are preparing to do the SharePoint 2010 farm. There is one database server for this farm. We have backups of the SharePoint Databases and backups of:

- Virtual Directories
- IIS Configuration
- SharePoint Configuration Settings
- GAC backup
- WSP Backups

My question is: if we shutdown the SharePoint farm, all services off. Rebuild the DB server (using the same server name and details), then reload the SharePoint SQL databases, then restart services - would that work?

The SharePoint SQL databases are not corrupted.

Please let me know if any more details are needed.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will works. Make sure following things:

- shutdown the SharePoint completely.
- Make sure after rebuild DB server DNS is same as per old. If you are not using the Alias.
- all the DBs should on same point and time restores(lets say all dbs restore time is 11:00PM).
- restart from Central Admin server after DB restores.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question Waqas, I appreciate it greatly. I am wondering if you could clarify point 3 in your response? Thanks!

Comment: Config DB is Time sensitive, so keeping that in mind, I said....Choose same time of BAckup for All DBs....11:00PM or 10:00PM but dont mix them with different times couple of 11:00Pm, couple of 10:30Pm etc

Comment: Thanks Waqas - I will mark as answer after I complete this restore and write up my experience.